# how to display data from multi level categories laravel?

Tags: laravel, navigation, multi-level

I have a table:

**products:**

- id
- title
- description

**categorys:**

- id
- parent_id
- name

product_categorys:

- product_id
- category_id

I use multi level navigation menu from category data.

How do I display data based on multi-level categories?
If I click on a category, it displays products based on the category I chose, and if there is a product from the derivative of the category, it will also appear. But if the category has no derivatives, it only displays products in that category.